# Parse... query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a query working.

```
Optional(<NewThread: 0x175a1c20, objectId: DipO5r7OXP, localId: (null)> {
Body = "This will be the initial comment when posting a new Thread.";
ShortDescript = "Short Description.";
Title = "Thread Title";
})
```

I get the info in parse back, but I am unable to pull the info out for use in the tableView Cell.

The query code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "NewThread")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(pinCode){
        (NewThread: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && NewThread != nil {

            println(NewThread)
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
```

I have tried everything I could find on the web, and I have watched literally dozens of how to videos and read countless tutorials, but have been unable to find anything that helps.

My question is: How do I extract the info from the search into a usable format for input to labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else statement you would use:

```
let newThreadBoy   = NewThread["body"] as! String
let ShortDescript  = NewThread["ShortDescript"] as! String
let newThreadTitle = NewThread["Title"] as! String
```

You can access Parse object properties like you would a Swift dictionary with subscripting.

Update, if your cell is a basic cell you would set the title from the parse object like this: (assuming you named your cell instance, 'cell')

```
cell.textLabel.text = newThreadTitle
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I just need to get that into the new cell label ;)

Comment: You're welcome, I've updated my answer with an example of how you would assign it in your cell. If the answer works please accept it.